# Slow Webservice Callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

[image]The question is about speeding up the loading of a ASP.NET web app, and I found that the loading time of the filtering feature of the web app is unacceptable. The filter list is generated from a database. Please see the following code:

This function is in .js and is invoking the webservice method.

```
function filterSetup() {
    filterChanged = true;
    var reset = true;
    DDL_WebService.fillFilter(SucceededCallbackWithContext, FailedCallback,new ddlContext("My_Filter", reset));
    filterSystemSetup();   
}
```

This function is in .js too and is executed after the webservice method.

```
function SucceededCallbackWithContext(result, userContext) {
    var ddl = $get(userContext.cntrl);
    var curVal = userContext.getVal();
    // Fetching result...
}
```

This function is one method in a web service file called "DDL_WebService.vb". It is in .vb and is getting the data from a database.

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function fillFilter() As List(Of String)
        Dim strSQL As String

        strSQL = "select '(All)' from My_Table "

        Return getData(strSQL)
    End Function
```

Problem: I thought after the last line of fillFilter(), it should go to SucceededCallbackWithContext()in almost no time (The step-into command tells me nothing happens in between too). However, getting to SucceededCallbackWithContext() from the last line of fillFilter() takes around 7 seconds.

I am not sure what is taking the time and how can I confirm and resolve that.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Updates:
Looking at the problem from another angle using Developer tool, I get the result shown in the sceenshot. Now my question becomes what are the possible reasons that some methods take too long to run (Note: For the webservice method with the longest request time, I speed up the query from 10 seconds to less than 3 seconds, but the request time is still arount 15 seconds). Could it be that the executing of one webservice method would affect the speed of another webservice method? Thanks again!
[image: The network traffic flow of the web tool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it has been a long time since I posted the question, I still want to update my progress on this problem just to thanks Beldi and mostafa for the suggestions and to give people some hints when having similar issues.

Overall the problem has not been resolve but we came up with a workaround.

We were guessing that some queries might take a long time to finish, so I carved out all the queries that take a long time according to the developer tool. I tested them one by one and found that they are all pretty fast. In the next quite a bit of time, I was stuck on verifying what the developer tool indicates.

One breakthrough happens when I dissect the following code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "dataservice/getSimData_WebService.asmx/getSimsList",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                var thegrid = $("#jqGrid_sims")[0];
                thegrid.addJSONData(data.d);
            }
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus) {
            alert("Error from get grid data");
        }
    });
```

In this piece of ajax call, the code sends out the request upon executing. The time between the beginning of the execution and the beginning of the if statement is requesting time, and that is the time the developer tool indicates.The time that code inside if statement spends is the fetching time.

After looking into the requesting time and the fetching time for each ajax call, I found the fetching time for a simulation functionality takes a relatively significant amount of time. Since loading the functionality would cause the page to be frozen and trying to reduce the frozen time has more uncertainties and takes longer, we finally decide to not load it initially. Instead, it will load once a user clicks on a button.

Hope this would help anyone who has similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to filter data why you try to load all records with all columns?
If your my_table records is around 1000 or less than 1000(I mean you have a small data set) you can not understand performance issue but after a while as your data grow(for example it reaches up to 100000) you notice that your service is getting slower and slower.

If you query is not your main query in code so first use browsers developer tools or any other tools to measure response time of your service to be sure that problem is in your server side codes or in your javascript codes

Comment: Thank you very much @mostafa, for inspiring me of using the developer tool. That helps a lot. I am not too sure but I think the problem is on the server side.

Comment: 15 second for service call with size of 40 kb, check query execution time, check mapping times, after that you can found source problem but I think that you have a table with too many records without indexed column

Answer (score 0):

Try to compress your datataTable before sending it !I share with you two functions thaallow the compression and decompression :

```
 Public Shared Function CompressData(ByVal ds As DataSet) As Byte()
        Try
            Dim data As Byte()
            Dim memStream As New MemoryStream()
            Dim zipStream As GZipStream = New GZipStream(memStream, CompressionMode.Compress)
            ds.WriteXml(zipStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
            zipStream.Close()
            data = memStream.ToArray()
            memStream.Close()
            Return data
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function


Public Shared Function DecompressData(ByVal data As Byte()) As DataSet
    Try
        Dim memStream As New MemoryStream(data)
        Dim unzipStream As New GZipStream(memStream, CompressionMode.Decompress)
        Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()
        objDataSet.ReadXml(unzipStream, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
        unzipStream.Close()
        memStream.Close()
        Return objDataSet
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @Beldi. I will definitely give it a try.